# Segmentation fault when debugging Qt application with gdb but run well without gdb

Tags: qt, gdb, segmentation-fault

I am using gdb-7.4-MINGW32_NT-6.1-i686 to debug my Qt application (Qt4.8.4 + QtCreator, OS Win7-x64), F5 to line 5 and it goes well

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include <QApplication>

0 - int main(int argc, char *argv[])
1 - {
2 -     int na = 0;
3 -     na += 10;
4 -     QString strabc = "abc";
5 -     strabc.clear();
6 -
7 -     QApplication a(argc, argv);
8 -     MainWindow w;
9 -     w.show();
10-    return a.exec();
11- }
```

Then F10 to the line 7, segmentation fault occurs.

However, If I use Ctrl+B and then Ctrl+R, it goes well and my application runs.
Could anyone tell me what happens and how to solve this problem? Thanks a lot!

PS: I've tried to do the same things on Win7-x86, everything just ok. And I have tried different versions of gdb, but all fail. My CPU is i7-6700, I doubt gdb's compatibility.

Comment: Could you please edit your post to replace F5, ctrl+B by the corresponding actions : go to next, etc. So it can be clearer.

Comment: In this very special case I am guessing the problem is a bug in the particular version of gdb you are running. I don't see any reason for a crash in your code.

Comment: Thanks for answering and advisement although it didn't help me. I think the error not caused by code but the environment